# CMOS Battery in MacBook Pro 2007

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

CMOS battery in my MacBook Pro (2007, pre-unibody) has died recently.

I am looking for a replacement, although all I could find so far was only used batteries off ebay.

It says following on the battery's shrink wrap:

```
CR2025/USTC
PW3+3V
7 8 21
```

Under the shrink wrap it says:

```
Panasonic
CR2025
3V
Made in Malasya
```

So I am wondering if I could simply take a good quality CR2025 battery and use it instead of buying a used one? Or is this some super-secret version of CR2025 only Apple managed to get its hands on and I'd better off getting a used one, although straight of a MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any standard [CR 2025](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001MQUOC) will do the trick.